# Binding a value to ConverterParameter

Tags: silverlight

I have a combobox control in xaml. Whatever is selected in combobox, I want it to be appended to the text in below TextBox. How can this be achieved?

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Entity.Value.Minvalue, 
                 Converter={StaticResource ConverterName}, 
                 ConverterParameter=???, 
                 Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Can we pass Entity/Property in ConverterParameter? Any pointers in the direction how it can be achieved are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <ComboBox x:Name="Cmb" Background="Red" Height="35" Width="300"  >
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem1"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem1"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem1"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="ComboBoxItem1"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=Cmb,Path=SelectedValue.Content,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Mode you can decide as per your requirement..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append text every time the SelectedItem changes for the ComboBox, you can listen to the SelectionChanged event and update the text.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Combo" ItemSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectionChanged="OnComboBoxSelectionChanged">
        <!-- define your template -->
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="AppendingText" Text=""/>
</StackPanel>
```

In your code begind, in the OnComboBoxSelectionChanged, add to the text

```
// You probably want to cast SelectedItem to your model and get a property from it
AppendingText.Text += Combo.SelectedItem.ToString();
```